# Javascript: Declaring a variable twice in the same line -- what does it mean (eg. Var x = this.time = this.time || this.time(); )

Tags: javascript

I recently found the following code, but I have never seen JS like this before. What does it mean, and does it work?

```
Var x = this.time = this.time || Data.now();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is a short form of,

```
this.time = this.time || Data.now();
Var x = this.time;
```

But you have to be careful while using this way of coding in other aspects like,

```
var a = b = 10;
```

Because here in the above case `b` will become a global variable.

Comment: does var a stay as a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation is done from right to left.

so `this.time || Data.now()` is evaluated first

As an logical OR statement it is evaluated from left to right

So the steps taken are

If `this.time` is defined then `this.time` is equal to itself otherwise `this.time` is equal to the current time.

last part is declaring a variable x that will be equal to whatever `this.time` is set as explained above

Answer (score 0):

When used in a variable assignment like this, the `||` operator acts as a default value mechanism. The statement is basically saying:

"Set `x` to `this.time`, unless `this.time` is not initialized, then use `Date.now()`".

For a lot more detail, see Addy Osmani's article on the `||` operator: https://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/

Answer (score 0):

This attribution of value occurs from the right to the left.

```
Var x = this.time = this.time || Date.now();
```

At the end `this.time` receive `Date.now()` if `this.time` is `undefined`. And `Var x` receive the `this.time` value;

You can declare multiple variables with one single value, simple like that in Javascript:
Eg

```
var name_a = 'Maria';
var name_b = 'Mario';
console.log(name_a);//Maria
console.log(name_b);//Mario

name_b = name_a = 'Paul';
console.log(name_a);//Paul
console.log(name_b);//Paul
```

[Mozzila Reference of Variables Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)